# mySQL installer - access to path is denied

Tags: mysql, database, installation, path

I'm trying to install mySQL 5.7.7, but on the 'Apply Server Configuartion' page the 'writing configuration file' fails and the log gives the error as:

'Could't find path 'C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\my.ini'

So then I manually added the folder and got this error:

'Access to the path 'C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\my.ini' is denied.'

Following advice online I've given 'Everyone' full-access to mySQL plus all files in the path, but I still keep getting the same error.

Any ideas? Much appreciated, thanks

Comment: try setting the user and group of the manually added folder structure to "mysql" and "mysql"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your `my.ini` file is not where it should be. To figure out exactly what his location is:

1. Open the Task Manager, go to the Services tab and then hit the Services button.
2. Search in the list for the service called 'MySQL56'. Right click on it, and hit Properties.
3. In the General tab, look for "Path to executable". After `--defaults-file=` you should see the exact path of the file `my.ini`.

If the file is in the folder you specified but you still can't access it, maybe you should try to reinstall.